# cuda - kernel optimization

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpu

I created a simple particle system. I have a device with compute capability 2.1. What could I change to optimize the kernel?

I assume that variables `tPos` and `tVel` are stored in the registers.

```
__global__ void particles_kernel(float4 *vbo, float4 *pos, float4 *vel)
{
     int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

     float4 tPos = pos[tid];
     float4 tVel = vel[tid];

     tPos.x += tVel.x;
     tPos.y += tVel.y;
     tPos.z += tVel.z;

     if(tPos.x < -2.0f)
     {
         tVel.x = -tVel.x;
     }
     else if(tPos.x > 2.0f)
     {
         tVel.x = -tVel.x;
     }


     if(tPos.y < -2.0f)
     {
         tVel.y = -tVel.y;
     }
     else if(tPos.y > 2.0f)
     {
         tVel.y = -tVel.y;
     }


     if(tPos.z < -2.0f)
     {
         tVel.z = -tVel.z;
     }
     else if(tPos.z > 2.0f)
     {
         tVel.z = -tVel.z;
     }


     pos[tid] = tPos;
     vel[tid] = tVel;


     vbo[tid] = make_float4(tPos.x, tPos.y, tPos.z, tPos.w);
}
```

Comment: That is going to be really difficult to answer without falling into generalities. You might want to have a look at "[Optimizing CUDA part I (PDF)](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_Webinars_CUDA_Optimization_April-2009.pdf)" and "[Optimizing CUDA part II (PDF)](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_Webinars_Further_CUDA_Optimization.pdf)" for some general hints and tips. Other excellent resources are "Programming Massively Parallel Processors" and "CUDA by Example".

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something, your clamping code can be simplified like this:

```
if (fabsf(tVel.x) > 2.0f) tVel.x = -tVel.x;
if (fabsf(tVel.y) > 2.0f) tVel.y = -tVel.y;
if (fabsf(tVel.z) > 2.0f) tVel.z = -tVel.z;
```

However given the relatively small amont of computation, this change will probably not improve performance as the code appears to be memory bound (you are streaming through the data). Maybe there is additional computation elsewhere in your app that you could combine with this computation to increase the computational density?

Comment: Yeah, this kernel is pretty trivial.  You might want to process multiple particles per thread in a loop -- do the loads for a few particles before the computations for those few so that you have more instructions to overlap with the memory accesses and more memory transactions in flight.  Otherwise, there's not much to optimize here.